Reuse base images in Dockerfile multi builds with different parameters
I have this Dockerfile that use multi-stage builds to run multiple commands on multiple subdirectories that generate slides. As you can see there is a lot of redundancy:
FROM node:22 AS build-base
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
RUN ...

FROM build-base AS build-A
ENV SLIDE_NAME="A"
COPY ./slides/$SLIDE_NAME .
RUN npx command on folder/$SLIDE_NAME/ & \
  other command using $SLIDE_NAME

FROM build-base AS build-B
ENV SLIDE_NAME="B"
COPY ./slides/$SLIDE_NAME .
RUN npx command on folder/$SLIDE_NAME/ & \
  other command using $SLIDE_NAME

FROM build-base AS build-C
...


FROM nginx:1.27.0-alpine
RUN rm -r /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=build-A /build/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build-B /build/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build-C /build/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html

I would love to reduce the "code duplication" and tried to do so with the usage of ARG:
FROM node:22 AS build-base
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
RUN ...
ARG SLIDE_NAME
COPY ./slides/$SLIDE_NAME .
RUN npx command on folder/$SLIDE_NAME/ & \
  other command using $SLIDE_NAME


FROM build-base AS build-A
ARG SLIDE_NAME="A"

FROM build-base AS build-B
ARG SLIDE_NAME="B"

...

Sadly it didn't work as $SLIDE_NAME was always an empty string.
So my first example works and enables a good layer caching. But do you know maybe another way to reduce a bit this redundancy?

Can you write a single command to build all of the slides at once?  Could your logic go into a shell script, instead of Docker-specific RUN directives?

I could but will take a long time. All those builds generate slides from a dedicated directory as a website and render them as a pdf. By splinting the build I let docker cache the build, so that when I update slides in a directory, docker doesn't need to build the slides for the others directories.

Could you use Make, or a similar build system?

@DavidMaze I would rather stay with what Docker can offer. Initially I had a nodejs script that run the command concurrently but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. Thanks for your time ☺

You can build N images running from slidex folder, then RUN all where you sharing a folder with the build, then build the "collector"  image where you simply COPY from the shared folders.

@Max yes but the N images are going to be redundant.

Yes of course, but you are limited to the time of COPY all files to the final image

@Max I updated my question because the issue is not the redundancy of the COPY command but the RUN that is the same on each build step definition.

If I understand correctly:
This part of Dockerfile creates ALL folders
FROM node:22 AS build-base
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
RUN ...


Then you have to iterate this code N times
FROM build-base AS build-X
ENV SLIDE_NAME="X"
COPY ./slides/$SLIDE_NAME .
RUN npx command on folder/$SLIDE_NAME/ & \
  other command using $SLIDE_NAME

In the final stage, you have to iterate COPY for the N result
COPY --from=build-X /build/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html

Possible Solutions
Create a script
With bash/PowerShell/bat/whatever create the code that creates the Dockerfile with the X parts
Create 2+1 Dockerfile

The first Dockerfile is the npm i part
The second Dockerfile is the RUN iteration part
The third Dockerfile is the 'COPY` iteration part (optional)

First
The First Dockerfile build all the slides
FROM node:22 AS build-base
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
RUN ...


You have to build and run the container mapping the build folders a.k.a. slides to local directory.
docker build -t myimage .
docker run -it myimage -v /localdirectory:/container/slides bash

Second
The second Dockerfile is the below code
FROM Node:22
# or use a WRKDIR
COPY . .
RUN npx command on . & \
  other command using .

then place the bash into the correct folder
/localdirectory the folder where is mapped the first container
Then build
docker build -t slideA ./slideA
You now have image for A slides and you can run it with mapping volume like the first image.
docker run --rm -it slideA -v /anotherlocalfolder:/containerA/build bash

copy what do you want from the mapped folder (into /usr/share/nginx/html) and close/kill the container
OR
run the third container passing the correct folder path (-v ....)

repeat until slideX (you can create a script)
Third
If you don't have docker code to RUN on copy, you can skip this image
Conclusion
Choose first or second solution is up to you (and your knowledge of coding)
| Warning: The above code is not tested use at your own risk
